# How to join multiple has_many relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Company` model that `has_many` `balances` and `prices`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :balances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :prices, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The `Balance` and `Price` both have an `date` and `amount` columns.

I want to get recent 10 item of `balances` and same date of `prices` for them.
This is the code I wrote:

```
c = Company.first
balances = c.balances.order(:date).last(10)
prices = Balance.where(date: balances.map(&:date))
```

I think It is better that to join `blances` and `prices` table at first and select from the table by `company_id` and `date`.
But I couldn't figure out how to write it.

How can I write it?

### Edit

I want to have a function like this in Rails way.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT "balances".*, prices.name FROM "balances" LEFT JOIN "prices" ON "balances"."date" = "prices"."date" where balances.company_id = 1 AND prices.company_id = 1 ORDER BY balances.date ASC').values.last(10)
```